# problems with final-form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

I have some problems with final-form. function `handleSubmit` don't calls anything. I checked official final-form example. I do identically that written there. But it's not working.

Here my form code:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import {Field, Form} from 'react-final-form';
import {IAddComponentProps} from "./interfaces";
import {EditContainer, StyledButton} from './styles';
import EditInput from "../EditInput";

const AddComponent: FunctionComponent<IAddComponentProps> = ({onSubmitForm, onEditInput}) => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmitForm}
      render={({handleSubmit}) => (
        <EditContainer onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <Field name={'addComment'}>
            {({input}) => (
              <EditInput {...input} onEditInput={onEditInput}/>
            )}
          </Field>
          <StyledButton>OK</StyledButton>
        </EditContainer>
      )}
    />
  )
};

export default AddComponent;
```

Here is my functions which I put into props:

```
const onChangeInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setInputValue(event.target.value)
  }

const onSubmitAddComment = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    const newComment: ICommentsData = {
      id: new Date().getMilliseconds(),
      cardId: cardId,
      name: author,
      comment: inputValue
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.reset()
    dispatch(actions.comments.addComment({newComment}))
    resetInputValue()
  }
```

Comment: How does that `<StyledButton>` component look like? Does it have a `<button>` inside with the `type="submit"` attribute?

Comment: @tromgy `<StyledButton>` in not component. I am using `styled-components` library. It is just a button with styles. I added `type="submit"`, but it doesn't works as well

Comment: And `<EditContainer>` is a styled `<form>`?

Comment: @tromgy yes, it is form

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this was, that i put into `onSubmit` of `Form` function from props. When i created function inside component it started working. So new code of my form is:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
import {Field, Form} from 'react-final-form';
import {IAddComponentProps} from "./interfaces";
import {EditContainer, StyledButton} from './styles';
import EditInput from "../EditInput";

const AddComponent: FunctionComponent<IAddComponentProps> = ({onSubmitForm, onEditInput}) => {

  const onSubmit = () => {
    onSubmitForm()
  }

  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      render={({handleSubmit,form}) => (
        <EditContainer onSubmit={(event) => {
          event.preventDefault()
          handleSubmit()
          form.reset()
        }}>
          <Field name={'addComment'}>
            {({input}) => (
              <EditInput {...input} onEditInput={onEditInput}/>
            )}
          </Field>
          <StyledButton>OK</StyledButton>
        </EditContainer>
      )}
    />
  )
};

export default AddComponent;
```